# Probability density of compound triangular distribution with uniformly distributed mode?

Tags: distributions, uniform-distribution, triangular-distribution

What are the probability density function and cumulative distribution function of a compound [triangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution) distribution with [uniformly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) distributed mode, both supported on $(-a, a)$?  *I.e.*,

$$
m \sim \mathrm{Unif}(-a, a) \\
X \sim \mathrm{Triang}(-a, a, m)
$$

Does it have a name?

It is not a [Wigner semicircle distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_semicircle_distribution) and it is close to a scaled, shifted beta distribution with $\alpha = \beta \approx 1.75$, but I'm interested in whether it has a simple closed form.

Comment: Yes, the PDF and CDF have closed forms.  Indeed, for $a=1$ (which loses no generality, since $a$ is a scale parameter) its cf can be written in terms of cosine and sine integrals as $${4 t^2}\psi(t)={e^{-i t} \left(2 \left(1+e^{2 i t}\right) \text{Ci}(2 t)+4 e^{i t}
   \text{Si}(2 t) \sin (t)+\log \left(-\frac{i}{t}\right) \\ -\log
   \left(-\frac{2 i}{t}\right)+\log (2 i t)-\log (4 i t)-2 (\log
   (t)+\gamma )-2 e^{2 i t} (\log (t)+\gamma +\log (2))\right)}$$ From that you can extract the moments.

Answer (score 5):

Given:  $X \sim \text{Triangular}(-a,m,a)$ with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/triangularpdfonaa.png))</sub>

where parameter $m$, instead of being fixed, is itself a random variable. In particular, $M \sim \text{Uniform}(-a,a)$, with pdf $g(m)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/uniformonaa.png))</sub>

Then, we seek the parameter mixture distribution $E_{g }\big[\;f (x \; \big | \;M =m )\big]$, which has pdf say $h(x)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/parammixtriuniform.png))</sub>

where I am using the `Expect` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* to automate the calculation. The domain of support is, of course, $(-a,a)$.

To illustrate, here is a plot of the pdf $h(x)$, as parameter $a$ varies:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/parammixpdfplotty.png))</sub>

The cdf $P_h(X<x)$ is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/parammixcdf.png))</sub>

**Comparison to semi-circle distribution**

The following diagram compares the pdf of the exact solution $h(x)$ to the semicircle pdf that the OP refers to. The pdf $h(x)$ is somewhat more peaked than the semi-circle:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/semicirclevsparammix.png))</sub>

**Comparison to POWER semi-circle distribution**

While the functional form is different, one can approximate the pdf $h(x)$ extremely well with a power semi-circle distribution of form:

$$ \phi(x) = k \left(a^2-x^2\right)^{3/4}$$

where $k = \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{9}{4}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{\pi } a^{5/2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)}$

The fit is so good that one can barely see any perceptible difference:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/powersemicirclevsexact.png))</sub>

Comment: +1.  Note that the "power semi-circle distribution" is a shifted rescaled Beta$(7/4,7/4)$ distribution.